# Henry Fingerprint Classification System Disrepency Among Articles

Tags: forensics

I know that the formula for fingerprint primary classifications is [1+(even finger value sum)]/[1+(odd finger value sum)]. So according to this formula and the Henry Classification System finger values, if a person has whorls on all ten fingers, then the classification ratio would be (1+31)/(1+31), which is 32/32. But some of the articles I have read say that it is actually 31/31 for a person with whorls on all ten fingers. Here are two articles that say that: [article 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=EXJHAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=31/31%20finger%20classification&source=bl&ots=6jJe5jGYpl&sig=tSrY3yVaJ8ekSeq0CoKx8kl6He8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidqZj92cvLAhUF4iYKHcfxANoQ6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=31%2F31%20finger%20classification&f=false) and [article 2](http://www3.pittsfield.net/sandbox/groups/lauraschneider/wiki/d37f3/attachments/9353c/Henry%20Fingerprint%20Classification.pdf?sessionID=08fc4d7b5136f904266ba2169d2200d7e48e9dcd) while other articles such as [article 3](http://www.criminaljustice.ny.gov/ojis/history/ph_am_hn.htm) say 32/32. To me, the first two articles did not add the +1 to the numerator and denominator. Which is correct?